# floating point exception in gzserver

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to get started with gazebo and I just about finished following the instructions here:

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.9/install

I installed using the pre-compiled binaries on Ubuntu 13.04.

I am having trouble starting gzserver however. It crashes with a floating point exception error. Does anyone have an insights? This is the output:

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version
1.9.0 Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License. 
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master 
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345 
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.1.198 
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4128/floating-point-exception-in-gzserver/) by [munnveed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/457/munnveed/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-08-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-08-10**:
Could you run it with gdb as well to get more info? It guess it would help figuring out the problem.

**Comment by [munnveed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/457/munnveed/) on 2013-08-16**:
So I'm running it on an Ubuntu 12.04 now, with no problems. I don't have the 13.04 anymore, so I'm can't debug.

**Comment by [chutsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/482/chutsu/) on 2013-09-05**:
I can confirm the bug, I'm running Arch Linux. I have uploaded the gdb in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/YcBPcxK7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This has been fixed in more recent versions of Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0